# spark UI - Understand metrics memory used

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Could you please help me understand the metrics on spark UI Memory: 10 MB Used (552.6 GB Total)

[image]

```
PartitionNumber.nbExecutors = conf.getInt("spark.executor.instances", 20)
PartitionNumber.nbPartitions = PartitionNumber.nbExecutors * conf.getInt("spark.executor.cores", 2) * 3
  conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", PartitionNumber.nbPartitions.toString())
```

Is it correct that the memory used is 10Mb and the available memory 552Gb ?

Any help or suggestions you could provide would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total memory **available** for all executors: 552.6 Gb and the total memory **used** by all executors: 10 Mb

You can see it in "Storage memory" column (memory available to a Spark executor for storing and caching rdds/dfs). Each executor uses 169.1 Kb out of 9.1 Gb and there are 61 execs:

61 * 169.1 Kb ~= 10 Mb
61 * 9.1 Gb ~= 555 Gb

Comment: so increase storage memory per executor make spark run faster?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that simple. The answer really depends on what your Spark program does and to what kind of data. There are a lot of ways to tune Spark, and memory is just one of the options. If you want to better understand and tune Spark - take a look at "High Performance Spark" book by Holden Karau.

Comment: If you want to speed up an existing program - you'll need to ask a narrower question and provide more info about data and how you process it